# Parse JSON from conversation service of watson in java

Tags: arrays, json, watson-conversation, watson

i am using a watson service and trying to build a chat box for my application, the response from the watson API is in the form of JSON which is as following:

```
   {
  "context": {
    "conversation_id": "00d5c35d-ab4e-47d3-a7fd-2b78d57df59f",
    "system": {
      "dialog_stack": [
        {
          "dialog_node": "root"
        }
      ],
      "dialog_turn_counter": 1.0,
      "dialog_request_counter": 1.0,
      "_node_output_map": {
        "node_4_1487236585212": [
          0.0
        ]
      },
      "dialog_in_progress": false
    }
  },
  "entities": [],
  "intents": [
    {
      "confidence": 1.0,
      "intent": "Hello"
    },
    {
      "confidence": 0.0,
      "intent": "GoodBye"
    }
  ],
  "output": {
    "log_messages": [],
    "text": [
      "Welcome to my conversation app"
    ],
    "nodes_visited": [
      "node1"
    ]
  },
  "input": {
    "text": "hii"
  }
}
```

Now in my application i need to get the data of the "output" key from the JSON response, and "text" key from the "output" key.

What i am trying to do is as following:

```
MessageRequest options = new MessageRequest.Builder().inputText(message).alternateIntents(true).context(context).build();



        MessageResponse response = service.message("93576d15-15a9-4029-bc07-41da7f2efa39", options).execute();


        context = response.getContext();

        /*System.out.println(context);*/

        System.out.println(response);

        try {
            JSONObject contObj = new JSONObject(response);

            System.out.println(contObj.getString("output"));


            JSONObject contObj1 = new JSONObject(contObj);
            System.out.println(contObj1);
            System.out.println("TEXT OUTPUT"+contObj1.getString("text"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now the sysout containing "output" gives the correct value, but sysout containing "text", gives null. 
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: which text value are you trying to access?

Comment: hi if you see in JSON shared, there is a key "output" and in that there is key"text", i am talking about that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi after so much of trouble searching the same on various websites, and getting no help, i tried playing with the **ctrl+space** option of eclipse and eventually got a solution for the same. Those who might face such issues in future can see to the code below for reference.

```
JSONObject contObj = new JSONObject(res);

            outputText = (contObj.getJSONObject("output").getJSONArray("text").get(0).toString());
            System.out.println("outputText: "+outputText);
```

This is what i have done to get the desired output. And thanks to everyone who has tried helping me on this issue.

Comment: That only gets one line of the output. Conversation can return multiple lines depending on how it's written.

Comment: yeah @SimonO'Doherty you are absolutely correct but in my case, it will return only one value, and in case multiple values are being returned then those can be tracked with the help of loop.

Comment: Alternatively one can use google gson project to read and work with JSON in Java, good doc and a lot of examples online.

Answer (score 0):

The "**text**" is not a string. It is an array. That's why `contObj.getString("text")` isn't working.

I don't know the syntax for Java, but in Javascript you could access it like `output.text[0]`, so you should do the same in your code.

Comment: hi @Danilo Silveira, 'contObj.getString("output")' is working fine, but when i try to extend my JSON parsing, and try to parse the **"text"** in the **"output"**, it gives a null.

Comment: Hey dude, i got a solution of the same, anyways thanks for your suggestion. you can see my own answer for reference.

Comment: Yeah... I made a mistake in my answer and just edited. But that's it: you had to get the first element of "text" array, not the "array" string. Cheers!